# Webpack 4 $.fn is not defined

Tags: jquery, npm, webpack-4

I am having a error. I can not use $.fn in my project. All lines with $.fn are undefined. I used webpack to bundle my app. I tried the "expose-loader" and this also not worked.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.dataTable.Api.register('editor()', function (opts) {
        table = this.tables();

        setOptions(opts);
        drawCallback(table);
        drawButtons();

        return this;
    });
```

Webpack 4 Config

...

```
plugins: [
            new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                Tether: 'tether',
                'window.Tether': 'tether',
                Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            })
```

...